# How to develop an Operator which could have a master Pod working and a standby to do failover?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

There's a concept [Operator](https://coreos.com/operators/) in k8s which will could provide a CRD and do some operations when watching ADD/UPDATE/DELETE events of the CR.

It's a common method to deploy two services for the purpose of high availability, one as the master to respond to requests and the other as a standby to do failover. I have heard that in k8s, controllers could use this method to do HA and APIServer offers the functionality to select master between the two services.
I have searched a lot but couldn't find an example as to how to use this feature in [Operator](https://coreos.com/operators/).

Any suggestions on how to do HA for [Operator](https://coreos.com/operators/) are appreciated.

Comment: I just saw an article about Operators, it might give you some insight [Operator](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-elasticsearch-operator)

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I have seen that blog and it only describes the basic concepts of Operator and the usage of ElasticSearch Operator. In this question I want to know how to do HA for Operator. Thanks any way :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are referring to procedure called [leader election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election). There is nice [blog post](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/01/simple-leader-election-with-Kubernetes.html) about leader election in kubernetes. Some internal kubernetes services requires this too, for example [kube-scheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/454074d2303424bd71ad340bdbf307aa4196a59d/plugin/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/BUILD#L48), since at moment only one scheduler can work.

Also, you can use other ways for leader election, maybe your language have library for leader election, via [consul](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/leader-election.html), etcd, zookeeper, etc.

Comment: That's it! Thank you. The machinery of leader election in Kubernetes could make Operator more available.